# What features capture the semantics of a sentence from a gien audio?

Tags: audio, spectrogram, mfcc

I have been thinking lately and looking up on what could be the possible features that capture the semantics of an audio and came across MFCC: MFCC features represent phonemes (distinct units of sound) as the shape of the vocal tract (which is responsible for sound generation) is manifest in them(layman language).

1. So is MFCC the only feature that can capture the semantics in an audio?
2. How well do spectrograms capture the actual semantics of a sentence(audio)? Or are scalograms a better alternative?

Comment: Is the question about speech recognition?

Comment: yes, was curious as to know how to capture the meaning of spoken words through speech.